# C++ program not responding to tile/cascade window from task bar

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wtl

I have a complicated program in C++ (hybrid of old-school Win32 and WTL) which does not respond to any taskbar tile/cascade request (i.e. right click on task bar and select "Cascade Windows" or "Show window side by side").  When I use spy++, I found that none of my window is receiving any window message, while other programs (in this case, Firefox) get a series of WM_GETMINMAXINFO, WM_SIZE, WM_PAINT ...

My frame window is styled as WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW.  I create several hidden windows before creating the frame window.  I have tested on multiple different OS'es and the symptoms are the same.  Is there any limitation or prerequisites for Windows shell to send out messages to my frame window?

Comment: Have you removed any menu items (like size) from the system menu?

Comment: No, but we do add menu items to it.

Comment: For what it's worth, Chrome and Spy++ also appear to be immune from these layout requests. Nobody at Chrome seems to know why either: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=900

Comment: Turns out the reason Spy++ doesn't do it is because it's elevated - so explorer can't send it the appropriate messages - any other app run as admin is also immune. Doesn't explain the Chrome case though.

Answer (score 2):

Windows sends the messages to the window which is represented by the taskbar button.

In your app, and I'm guessing a bit here, it is one of the hidden windows which is represented by the taskbar button. The window manager won't send any of these messages to a hidden window.

You can solve the problem by arranging that the main window is the one represented in the taskbar.  You can read all about the gory details of which windows appear in the taskbar in the excellent MSDN topic titled [Window Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The odd part is the I've spied all windows (including hidden window) using spy++ and none of them receive any message from taskbar.  BTW, how do I tell which window is represented by the taskbar button?

Comment: Chrome suffers from the same problems (not responding correctly to tiling), although I'm not 100% sure why it struggles. The text displayed in the taskbar button is the window text of the window in question (what you set with a call to SetWindowText or a WM_TEXT message). If this text is the same as the caption of your main form then my guess is wrong and I'll delete the answer. If my hunch is right then AeroPeek should not work for your app.

Comment: Yes, it's my main frame window and the text is the same.  On Windows 7, the preview window is shown correctly, Windows+arrow keys works as expected, just the tiling/cascading don't work.  Odd enough, my notepad.exe does not tile/cascade on some Windows 7 machines, either.  I wish some guru in StackOverflow can answer this.

Comment: What's the answer to the question asked by Tergiver in the comment? Can you run your app without the hidden windows?

Comment: For your main window do you pass anything to hWndParent when you call CreateWindowEx?

Comment: @David: Did not see anything from Tergiver.  I can't run without hidden windows.  The hWndParent I passed in is NULL.

Comment: It's in a comment to your question. Tergiver asks: "Have you removed any menu items (like size) from the system menu?" What is the answer?